# ManyToOne cascade remove fails because of OrderBy annotation

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have two entities : an Annonceur can have many Publicite, a Publicite is owned by a single Annonceur :

Annonceur entity :

```php
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Publicite::class, mappedBy="annonceur", orphanRemoval=true, cascade={"remove"})
     * @ORM\OrderBy({"id" = "RAND"})
     */
    private $publicites;
```

The `OrderBy` annotation is used to get Publicite in random order.

Publicite entity :

```php
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Annonceur::class, inversedBy="publicites")
     */
    private $annonceur;
```

In my controller, when I wan to delete an instance on Annonceur I have this error message :

> `Doctrine\ORM\Persisters\Exception\InvalidOrientation: Invalid order by orientation specified for App\Entity\Publicite#id in /home/sami/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Persisters/Exception/InvalidOrientation.php:13`

Removing the `OrderBy` annotation fix the problem, but I need to keep it !

Comment: I don't think *rand* is supported with relations like this [[REF](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.17/reference/annotations-reference.html#orderby)]. What you should probably do is create a specific method within your *Publicites* entity, *getRandomizedPublicites()* for example, and create the relevant logic that way using Criteria to randomise the ordering.

Answer (score 0):

RAND() is not a native function in Doctrine, it shouldn't be used like this.
You must create a function in your repository and call this custom function.